# Qual o sentido de criar uma classe dentro de outra?

Tags: python

Qual o sentido de definir uma classe dentro de outra? A pergunta surgiu ao estudar Peewee, framework de persistência. Vejam o código:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.sqlite3')


class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db


class Phone(Model):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='phones')
    number = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db


db.connect()
db.create_tables([Person, Phone])

person = Person(name='Luciano')
person.save()
```

Quis entender um pouco melhor o que estava a acontecer, então, acrescentei um `print(dir(person))` e obtive o seguinte:

> ['DoesNotExist', '**class**', '**data**', '**delattr**', '**dict**',
> '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**',
> '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**',
> '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**',
> '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**rel**', '**repr**',
> '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**sql**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**',
> '**weakref**', '_coerce', '_dirty', '_meta', '_normalize_data', '_pk',
> '_pk_expr', '_populate_unsaved_relations', '_prune_fields', '_schema',
> 'add_index', 'alias', 'bind', 'bind_ctx', 'bulk_create',
> 'bulk_update', 'clone', 'coerce', 'copy', 'create', 'create_table',
> 'delete', 'delete_by_id', 'delete_instance', 'dependencies',
> 'dirty_fields', 'drop_table', 'filter', 'get', 'get_by_id', 'get_id',
> 'get_or_create', 'get_or_none', 'id', 'index', 'insert',
> 'insert_from', 'insert_many', 'is_alias', 'is_dirty', 'name', 'noop',
> 'phones', 'raw', 'replace', 'replace_many', 'save', 'select',
> 'set_by_id', 'table_exists', 'truncate_table', 'unwrap', 'update',
> 'validate_model']

Parece que o atributo _meta se refere à classe Meta, então, com `print(dir(person._meta))`, investigo o que ela contém:

> ['**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**',
> '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**',
> '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**',
> '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**',
> '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
> '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_additional_keys', '_db_hooks',
> '_default_by_name', '_default_callable_list', '_default_callables',
> '_default_dict', '_schema', '_sorted_field_list', '_table',
> '_update_sorted_fields', 'add_field', 'add_manytomany', 'add_ref',
> 'auto_increment', 'backrefs', 'columns', 'combined', 'composite_key',
> 'constraints', 'database', 'defaults', 'depends_on', 'entity',
> 'fields', 'fields_to_index', 'get_default_dict', 'get_primary_keys',
> 'get_rel_for_model', 'indexes', 'legacy_table_names',
> 'make_table_name', 'manytomany', 'model', 'model_backrefs',
> 'model_graph', 'model_refs', 'name', 'only_save_dirty', 'options',
> 'primary_key', 'refs', 'remove_field', 'remove_manytomany',
> 'remove_ref', 'schema', 'set_database', 'set_primary_key',
> 'set_table_name', 'sorted_field_names', 'sorted_fields', 'table',
> 'table_function', 'table_name', 'table_settings', 'temporary',
> 'without_rowid']

Há uma porção de métodos pré-definidos. De alguma forma que não entendo, a classe Meta foi herdada d'alguma outra classe que não está clara.

Assim, pergunto:

1. Qual o sentido de criar uma classe dentro da outra?
2. Por que ""meta" não poderia ser um atributo da classe, objeto criado por composição?

Answer (score -2):

O sentido de criar uma classe dentro de outra classe é uma questão de escopo e organização. Usa-se quando essa classe está relacionada com o contexto da outra. Também pode servir para agrupar várias classes dentro de um namespace.

As vantagens são o agrupamento lógico de classes, o encapsulamento e tornar o código mais legível e fácil de manter.

Usamos uma classe em vez de um objeto porque com um classe podemos instanciar vários objetos.